# Telegram Bot send message to another @username

Tags: telegram-bot

everyone) When a user push button, BOT should send a message to another @username as a text, I mean, this message will be forward to another profile

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Hello, I wanted to create a bot and in this bot I have to add 2 simple keyboards and in the first keyboard the bot should set the request for the user to "not participate" and when the user pressed the keyboard the bot should show 3 requests here is 1 "for the first lesson" 2 " for the second  lesson "3" for a day "and of course input" back to the main "

Comment: then when the user clicked on one of the bot should give the keyboard for the reason in the text type and the last thing is to send those messages to the admin or to the shown @username here type of such message "Your student will not participate tomorrow in the first lesson and  cause.... "

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?